# How do I add an array of custom objects to a Firestore document field?

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update or create a field called "tags" inside a document, which should contain an array of custom objects called Tags ("tag_name", "tag_color"). To update or create such a field, I must pass an array of said object (not able to pass single objects, since it would be ineffective and expensive). How can I achieve this? I have tried adding an `ArrayList` of Tag objects to a Hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<GenericTagModel>> myObject = new HashMap<>();
                ArrayList<GenericTagModel> toArrayList = new ArrayList<GenericTagModel>(usedModels);
                myObject.put("tags",toArrayList);
                db.collection("users").document(user.getUid()).set(myObject, SetOptions.merge());
```

But all this does is add a field with nothing inside of it: "tags:[]"

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `tags:[]` because your `toArrayList` empty, does **not** contain any `GenericTagModel` objects. To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<GenericTagModel>> myObject = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<GenericTagModel> toArrayList = new ArrayList<GenericTagModel>(usedModels);
toArrayList.add(new GenericTagModel("redTag", "Red")); //Populate ArrayList
toArrayList.add(new GenericTagModel("blueTag", "Blue")); //Populate ArrayList
toArrayList.add(new GenericTagModel("greenTag", "Green")); //Populate ArrayList
myObject.put("tags",toArrayList);
db.collection("users").document(user.getUid()).set(myObject, SetOptions.merge());
```

The result will be an array that will contain theree `GenericTagModel` objects.

Comment: I know that the Array is not empty, i even checked in debug mode, still it is empty. Maybe a bug?

Comment: If know that the array is empty then populate it. Add `GenericTagModel` to it as in the highlighted lines, right? Does it work now?

Comment: Where is populated? Show the entire code where you populate the `ArrayList`. There is nothing in your code that shows that.